# wordpress domain name not working on lan + wamp server

Tags: php, wordpress

i setup my wordpress site on my computer by using wamp server and every thing is ok ,
i can access my site via lan or wan by using the ip address like :

```
       192.168.1.11/site
```

my host file like this :

```
        127.0.0.1               demo.it 

        127.0.0.1               www.demo.it

        192.168.1.11            demo.it
```

my vhost file like this

```
       <VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName demo.it
                DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/point"
             <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/point">
                Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
             </Directory>
       </VirtualHost>
```

i can browse the site on my computer by using the domain (demo.it) , but it's not working from other machine

help please

sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to enter the IP address of your local machine and the domain name as you have in your hosts file into any machine that wants to access your local wamp server.

`192.168.1.11            demo.it`

Of course, first the other machines must be able to reach 192.168.1.11, but as you said, they can access your site from http://192.168.1.11/site so that must mean they can reach you.

Just check via ping to be double sure. Open Command prompt and check output of

`ping 192.168.1.11`

If you can, there might be a way to configure your router or switch such that specific domain requests are routed to your IP address, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: thanks for your quick respond :) , the issue is that some of my users who will access the site find it so hard to remember the IP address so they prefer a simple (domain name) instead , any idea ?